# Vertex Slide (GG) Doesn't Work Properly on Complex Shapes

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, tools

I am trying to slide all the vertices of the object shown below using vertex slide (shortcut <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>G</kbd> in Blender 3.0.0). It works great on simple shapes like a circle of a triangle but for something complex like this, it doesn't shift a few vertices no matter what I try. I have tried merging close-by vertices already and it didn't help.

Before:
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

Comment: Are these blue lines face normals or edge normals ?

Comment: You should edge slide in a view perpendicular to the desired motion.  Testing with a similar home shape, it slides just fine.  Can you provide a file to recreate?